Running a clean build in a gradle kotlin 1.9.* with detekt 1.23.* has no effect
When running clean build, detekt does not react in any way to obvious (unused imports) or any other errors in the source code. Launching through detekt or detektBaselineMain also completes successfully.
what i use:
gradle 7.4 with wrapper,
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.23.1"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.7.6"
    id("org.ajoberstar.grgit") version "4.1.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.23"
}

I tried playing with versions, 1.19.0 seems to work well, but I would like to bump it up to 1.23.*

This solution helped, but it looks temporary
configurations.matching { it.name == "detekt" }.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") {
            useVersion("1.9.0")
        }
    }
}

